# function call with actual code

Tags: c

what I'm trying to do is take this function call...

```
assign_sum_to_pixel(&current_pixel, sum);
```

and replace it with the actual code that it calls which is this...

```
/* 
 * assign_ sum_ to_ pixel - Computes averaged pixel value in current_pixel 
 */


static void assign_ sum_ to_ pixel (pixel *current_ pixel, pixel_ sum sum) 

{

    current_ pixel->red = (unsigned short) (sum.red/sum.num);
    current_ pixel->green = (unsigned short) (sum.green/sum.num);
    current_ pixel->blue = (unsigned short) (sum.blue/sum.num);
    return; 

}
```

What I came up with was this...

```
/*
 * mysmooth1 - my smooth1 
 */


char mysmooth1_descr[] = "my smooth1: My smooth1";

void mysmooth1(int dim, pixel *src, pixel *dst)

{

    int i, j;
    int ii, jj;
    pixel_ sum sum;
    pixel current_ pixel;

    for (i = 0; i < dim; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < dim; j++)
    {
    initialize_ pixel_ sum (&sum);
    for(ii = max(i-1, 0); ii <= min(i+1, dim-1); ii++) 
    for(jj = max(j-1, 0); jj <= min(j+1, dim-1); jj++) 
        accumulate_ sum(&sum, src[RIDX(ii, jj, dim)]);
    {
    ***current_ pixel->red = (unsigned short) (sum.red/sum.num);
    current_ pixel->green = (unsigned short) (sum.green/sum.num);
    current_ pixel->blue = (unsigned short) (sum.blue/sum.num);***    


    ***(These three lines above are the lines I inserted which is where the function call use to be)***

    dst[RIDX(i, j, dim)] = return;

    }
    }
}
```

**but...for some reason when I run the code it fails to work  giving me this error**

```
kernels.c:456: error: invalid type argument of â->â

kernels.c:457: error: invalid type argument of â->â

kernels.c:458: error: invalid type argument of â->â

kernels.c:459: warning: statement with no effect
```

**which is right where I added the new code ...**

```
current_ pixel->red = (unsigned short) (sum.red/sum.num);

current_ pixel->green = (unsigned short) (sum.green/sum.num);

current_ pixel->blue = (unsigned short) (sum.blue/sum.num);
```

can someone tell me if I'm doing something wrong... Am I missing brackets somewhere? am I not initializing my variables correctly? is return not supposed to be at the bottom equaling to `dst[RIDX(i, j, dim)]` any help, comments, suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: Why are you trying to inline by hand? Keep the functions separate, it's cleaner, and the compiler will inline it for you if it determines that it will be beneficial. It will know that better than you or I.

Comment: Also, you have a bunch of spaces in variables, function names, etc... are these actually present in your code?

Comment: Not to mention the error message has non-ascii characters in it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `current_pixel` is a `pixel`, while previously you passed `&current_pixel`, a `pixel *` (pointer to pixel). So, you now need to use `current_pixel.red` (with a dot), **not** `current_pixel->red` (with a "right-pointing arrow"), which needs a pointer on the left hand side of the arrow; and so forth.

Answer (score 4):

Don't inline by hand. [Use the inline keyword](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_function) or better, let the compiler decide.

Comment: This is more of a comment, not an answer.

Comment: This is an answer, not a comment.  +1

Comment: It's sound advice, not an answer. These kind of answers belong at the end of a real answer, such as Alex's. If you asked a question about linked lists and somebody said, "Use an array" as an answer, would you consider it helpful? I wouldn't, even though it might be good advice. Help him with his code, and explain why functions should be left to be inlined by the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

If you must force inlining, you'd be better off using a macro

```
#define ASSIGN_SUM_TO_PIXEL (current_pixel, sum)\
do {\
    current_pixel.red = (unsigned short) (sum.red/sum.num);\
    current_pixel.green = (unsigned short) (sum.green/sum.num);\
    current_pixel.blue = (unsigned short) (sum.blue/sum.num);\
} while(0)
```

then use it as

```
for (i = 0; i < dim; i++)
for (j = 0; j < dim; j++)
{
initialize_pixel_sum (&sum);
for(ii = max(i-1, 0); ii <= min(i+1, dim-1); ii++) 
for(jj = max(j-1, 0); jj <= min(j+1, dim-1); jj++) 
    accumulate_sum(&sum, src[RIDX(ii, jj, dim)]);
{
    ASSIGN_SUM_TO_PIXEL (current_pixel, sum);
    ...
```

At least that way the code is kept separated in source.